# How to check if file exists using wildcard * in Erlang?

Tags: file, erlang, erlang-supervisor

Imagine a directory with these files/folders: file_foo, file_bar, folder_a, folder, b

I  need to search within this folder for a file which is named something with "foo". In `bash` I would normally do this by:

```
FOO_FILES=$(find . -name "*foo*")
```

**How to check if file exists using wildcard * in Erlang?**

Possible Soultions:

1. Do I need to use `file:list:dir` to list the directories files/folders and then iterate oder the list using a regurlar expression matching my search pattern? Or is there a simpler way to do so?
2. I tried using `file:path_eval("D:/myFolder", "*foo*")` but this did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [filelib:wildcard/1,2](https://erlang.org/doc/man/filelib.html#wildcard-1)